# Recommend decent, sturdy steamer basket?

Tags: equipment

I've gone through a couple of cheap metal collapsible steamer baskets in the last year and am looking for something that will last longer.  Do you have one that you like?  I've seen the silicon ones but have read that it may alter the taste of the vegetables. What is your experience?

Comment: Have you tried the standard Asian bamboo steamers? They are effective, dirt cheap (especially if you have an Asian supermarket nearby) and durable.

Answer (score 5):

I've commented this but I may as well make it an answer.

Asian bamboo steamers are cheap, especially at Asian supermarkets. They're also durable, easy to clean, and usually come in layers so you can steam multiple dishes at once (for example fish and vegetables).

[image]

Comment: Not to mention different diameters.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the bamboo steamers (which are great), I can also recommend finding a steamer insert which fits one or more pots you have.  This is far easier to lift out of a pot than a basket, and also easier to clean.

Examples:

- http://www.chantal.com/steamer_colander_lg.html
- http://www.williams-sonoma.com/products/3872660/?catalogId=83&cm_ven=Shopping&cm_cat=Froogle&cm_pla=default&cm_ite=default&ci_src=14110944&ci_sku=3872660

I have a steamer insert with a single, long pot handle which fits a 4qt pot and holds around 2qt of veggies.  This is even better than a two-handled one.  I couldn't find links to one, though.